# R in SharePoint

Tags: r, sharepoint, rexcel

What's the best way to have R functionality in MS SharePoint? Would RExcel work if I import an Excel sheet in SharePoint using Excel Services? Any other options?

Answer (score 3):

If you have SharePoint you must have a SQL Server license, thus why not make a table or database called R_DataAnalysis and then use [PowerPivot](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Power-Pivot-Add-in-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045) or [PowerView](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Power-View-Explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-98268d31-97e2-42aa-a52b-a68cf460472e?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) with [SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) to display your data?

Answer (score 1):

R exports to flat file very easily with:
`write.csv(dataframe,'someFile.csv')`

These can easily be imported for use in SharePoint BI functionality.